# Can't get call log in background (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-permissions, background-process

I'm able to get **CallLog** in Foreground with the `call_log` pub package. But I need to get Call Log in Background.

Here is some neccesery part of my code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ));

  Workmanager.initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: true);
  Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask("1", "simplePeriodicTask",
      existingWorkPolicy: ExistingWorkPolicy.replace,
      frequency: Duration(minutes: 15),
      initialDelay:
          Duration(seconds: 5),
      constraints: Constraints(
        networkType: NetworkType.connected,
      ));
}

void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async{
    await _HomeState().callLogDbManager();
    print('Background Services are Working!');
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Future<void> callLogDbManager() async {
    Iterable<CallLogEntry> cLog = await CallLog.get();
    int rowCount = await DatabaseHelper.instance.queryRowCount();
    int clLength = cLog.length;
    if (rowCount >= clLength) {
      callLogDbUpdate();
    } else {
      await callLogDbInsert();
      callLogDbUpdate();
    }
  }
  .......
  .......
}
```

And this is the Error during getting call log in Background:

[image]

error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference, null

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty much a limitation of the `CallLog` plugin. As you can see https://github.com/4Q-s-r-o/call_log/blob/af10fded3971b1c2065faa1813a9eeb993f3d9c4/android/src/main/java/sk/fourq/calllog/CallLogPlugin.java#L52 the plugin requires an active `Activity`

But to be honest I think, especially since CallLog access is a very specific Android problem, I don't really see the benefit of coding your logic in flutter/dart. Maybe you should go native for that part of your app, especially because you will run into problems when doing background logic anyway. Flutter support for background execution is still pretty messy: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32164